# What type of test should be used in this case?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python, nonparametric

I have a pandas data frame with a target variable, which is binary (classes `progressive` / `non-progressive`), that I want to predict. Before making the model I want to do some feature selection, and that is by comparing the density distribution of each predictive feature, between the two groups in the target variable.

For example, one predictive feature is T-cells, and comparing the density between the two groups looks something like this:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=12,8

# set seaborn whitegrid theme
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Without transparency
sns.kdeplot(data=dataframe, x="CD8+ T-cells", hue="PD", cut = 0, fill=True, common_norm=False, alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I want to perform a statistical test to see in which predictive feature, the difference is significance (so use only the features which show significant difference between the two target groups).

I cant use t-test or parametric tests for that matter, because it assumes normal distribution for the features. The features are not normal as you can see here:

[image]

so which non-parametric test can I use? My data contains this much of features as shown in the picture (around 40), and about 1500 samples.

Comment: When you say " significant difference between the two target" how do you define this difference? e.g. the t-test is for differences in population means, other tests do other specific things. What do you want to test for?

Comment: @utobi I'm really not sure to be honest. For example wilcoxon test is defined as "The tests essentially calculate the difference between sets of pairs and analyze these differences to establish if they are statistically significantly different from one another."

Comment: that's also a test for differences in locations of two distributions, although the locations are not the means. Others s.t. the KS test is for equality in distributions. So you can really apply a lot of different tests, e.g. even a t-test on the transformed samples. The point is, however another one: what are you going to do with them once you reject or accept the null?

Comment: If the feature I'm testing has no significant difference, I will not use it. I want only the features that are informative, that can show significant difference, between the progressive and non progressive groups. I think the KS test won't be suitable here since it basically checks if the two sampled groups comes from the same distribution, if I'm not mistaken.